# Weird dataTable behaviour when combined with accordionPanel

Tags: primefaces, datatable, accordionpane

I get a very strange behaviour when I combine the accordionPanel (dynamic tabs) together with a dataTable. In my project the total amount of dynamic tabs can get really big (>1000) so I really need the dynamic loading of the accordionPanel working, otherwise it is way too slow.

### The problem

Instead of only loading the datatable for the currently selected tab, the getter method to load the elements from a list variable is being called 6 times the total amount of dynamic tabs. So if I have 300 dynamic tabs, the getter method is called 1800 times. If I however do not use a dataTable but i.e. just output text, the getter method is only called once like it should be.

Here is a small working example which produces the unwanted behaviour:

### xhtml

```
<p:accordionPanel id="datasetHistoryAccordionTab" value="#{Bean.orderDatasets}" var="dataset" dynamic="true">
                            <p:tab title="Dataset ##{dataset.id}">
                                <p:tabView>
                                    <p:tab title="All Processes">
                                        <p:dataTable value="#{Bean.datasetProgressHistoryAll}" />
                                        <!-- <h:outputText value="#{Bean.datasetProgressHistoryAll}" /> -->
                                    </p:tab>
                                </p:tabView>
                            </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

### Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable
{
    private List<DatasetBE> orderDatasets = new ArrayList<DatasetBE>(300);      
    private List<DatasetHistoryBE> datasetHistoryAll = new ArrayList<DatasetHistoryBE>();

    public List<DatasetBE> getOrderDatasets() {
        return orderDatasets;
    }

    public void setOrderDatasets(List<DatasetBE> orderDatasets) {
        this.orderDatasets = orderDatasets;
    }

    public List<DatasetHistoryBE> getDatasetHistoryAll() {
        log.debug("getDatasetHistoryAll() called...");
        return datasetHistoryAll;
    }

    public void setDatasetProgressHistoryAll(List<DatasetHistoryBE> datasetHistoryAll) {
        this.datasetHistoryAll = datasetHistoryAll;
    }
}
```

The initial state is OK but as soon as I change to another tab the getter method is being called like crazy...

Is this a bug in PrimeFaces or am I doing something wrong? In my project I still use PF 3.5 but for testing purposes I also tried PF 4.0 but the same strange behaviour applies... Any help would be greatly appreciated!